# Scala Sets Immutability

Tags: scala, immutability

```
scala> var immSet = Set("A", "B")
immSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(A, B)

scala> immSet += "C"

scala> println(immSet)
Set(A, B, C)
```

I wonder, what is the advantage I am getting by allowing `var` to be used with with an immutable Set? Am I not losing immutability in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the advantage I am getting by allowing `var` to be used with
>   with a Immutabable `Set`s?

I would say this can mainly cause confusion. The fact that you're using a `var` allows you to *overwrite the variable*, but, the `Set` by itself *doesn't change*, it allocates a new set with the additional value "C". But since you're using a `var`, the previous `Set` is now no longer referenced, unless you've referenced is somewhere else higher up the stack:

```
scala> var firstSet = Set("A", "B")
firstSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(A, B)

scala> var secondSet = firstSet
secondSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(A, B)

scala> firstSet += "C"

scala> firstSet
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(A, B, C)

scala> secondSet
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(A, B)
```

Because `secondSet` still points to the `Set` created by `firstSet`, we don't see the value update reflected. I think making this immutable adds clarity that the underlying `Set` is immutable and well as the variable pointing to it. When you use a `val`, the compiler will yell if you attempt to reassign, forcing you to realize that a new collection is initialized.

Regarding immutability, we need to divide this into two. There is the immutability of the `Set`, and there is the immutability of the variable pointing to that `Set`, these are two different things. You lose the latter with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !!! I wonder if my set is immutable, I would like my variable also to be immutable, I wonder in which scenario  in real world we would like to have set to be immutable but variable don't ..

Comment: @JackDaniel's I understand. I just wanted to point out that doing this in real life may be confusing to whomever reads your code.

Comment: @JackDaniel's One reason to do it is that you can pass this set to any function and be sure it won't change (and that function also doesn't need to worry about you changing the `var` if it stores the set somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Read @YuvalItzchakov's answer if you want to understand what is the basic difference between immutable collection defined as `var` and mutable collection defined as `val`.  I'll concentrate on practical aspects of both approaches.

First of all, both approaches imply mutability. If you want to stay "pure functional" you should avoid either of them.

Now, if you want mutable collection, what is the best way?  Short answer, it depends.

1. Performance. Mutable collections are usually faster than their immutable counterparts. It means, that if your mutable variable is somehow contained (for example, doesn't escape private method), it may be better to use `val c = MutableCollection()`. Most of the Scala's methods in Collections API internally use mutable collections.
2. Thread safety. Value of immutable collection is always thread safe. You can send it to another thread and don't think about visibility and concurrent changes.

   ```
   var a = ImmutableCol()
   otherThreadProcessor.process(a)
   a += 1 // otherThread will still have previous value
   ```

   On the other hand, if you want to modify collection from multiple threads, better use Java's concurrent collection API.
3. Code clarity.  Imagine you have some function that takes collection as an argument and then modifies it in some ways. If collection is mutable, then, after function returns, collection, passed as an argument, will stay modified.

   ```
   def recImmutable(a:Set[Int]): Unit = {
     var b = a
     b += 4
   }

   val a = Set(2,3)
   recImmutable(a)
   println(a)
   // prints Set(2, 3)

   def recMutable(a:mutable.Set[Int]): Unit = {
     var b = a
     b += 4
   }

   val b = mutable.Set(2,3)
   recMutable(b)
   println(b)
   // prints Set(2, 3, 4)
   ```

Comment: Regarding the first point, *I think* the OP was referring to the specific scenario of using immutable collections with mutable variables, not of using mutable collections in general.